# How to append values to an ArrayList?

Tags: collections

How to put the results of this if condition in a array list?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GreatestCommonDivisor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Please enter a value whose GCD to be computed");
         int number = scan.nextInt();
         
         for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
             if(number%i==0) {
                 ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(number) {
                     
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GCD stands for Greatest Common Divisor...which finds the greatest number that divides all the numbers that you specify, but in your code I just see one number.

So from your code I get the idea that you wish to find all the numbers less than 10 (inclusive) that divide *number* and store those numbers in an arraylist. Assuming my assumption to be correct you can do the following.

Declare your arraylist before the loop:

```
     ArrayList<Integer>arr = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

Now run the loop:

```
    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
      if(number%i==0){
        v.add(i);
      }
    }
```